# Where are the Assemblies Located for Installed Nuget Packages When Using .Net Core?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, .net-core

I don't seem to be able to find the actual *.dll files. There's a whole lot of references to them, but none appear to have a file path.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

On Windows, you will find nuget packages and corresponding dll at this location `C:\Users\%username%\.nuget\packages`

For managing nuget cache refer this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-nuget-cache).

On windows you need to download the nuget command line tool from [here](https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/latest/nuget.exe).

Open a command prompt with directory to which `nuget.exe` was downloaded on your machine.

You can list the local caches with this command:

```
nuget locals all -list
```

You can clear all caches with this command:

```
nuget locals all -clear
```

Reference: https://docs.nuget.org/consume/command-line-reference

Comment: So on a computer running the code, the nuget packages just get dumped into a globally accesible folder. That's...strange. Doesn't that mean that in order to run a .NET Core application for the first time, you need to be connected to the internet?

Comment: NB: On my machine (Windows 7) the packages were under `C:\Users\%username%\.nuget\packages`... Not sure if that's a typo in the given answer, or something unique to my scenario; hence posting as a comment rather than an edit.  Thanks for the answer though; it still helped me find what I was after.

Comment: It wasn't a typo, it was just written as <user_name>, and since Stack Overflow excludes text wrapped within < > signs, they were not visible, I just edited and should be visible once my edit is applied

Comment: @Benjamin no, when you use `dotnet publish` it will copy the required dependencies to the output folder, these files should be distributed with the rest of your application.